# EAS Build stuck at the level of compressing files

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I am new to react-native and using expo.

I am trying to build an apk for the app I made. I have tried ESA build but once I run the build command it gets stuck hours  at `compressing project files and uploading to expo servers` and eventually fails.

I have tried creating a blank project to build but it still takes hours and sometimes a blank project (default expo app) compresses the files to a size of 66Gb and start uploading then fails shortly after.

Have been stuck with this issues for weeks.

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko0Al.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this issue.  I am using VS code but it showed no error.  when I ran the build command in the Mac terminal instead it showed an error that I could then debug.  it turned out that I needed to do a git init on the project folder.  This resolved the issue and my project is building fine now.

Answer (score 0):

yes as it was rightly answered doing a git init will solve the issues, the problem was the code was trying to compress all files in your project including node_modules and other heavy folders so, it will work when you just git init

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).